# How do i reset the timer in javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have a timer that begins when my application loads. But i want to reset my timer on click of button. But when i try to reset the timer weird values starts getting displayed in timer section.

Please find my code below:

HTML:

```
    <font size="4"><span class="myClass" id="time">02:00</span></font>   
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
            {
                var minute = 60 * 2,
                display = document.querySelector('#time');
                begin(minute, display);

            });


function myFunction()
{
var minute = 60 * 2,
display = document.querySelector('#time');
begin(minute, display);

}

    function begin(duration, display) {
                var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
                setInterval(function () {
                    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
                    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

                    if (--timer < 0) 
                    {
                        timer = duration;
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
```

Comment: Totally off topic, but why not call myFunction in document ready?  That's all you seem to be doing in there anyway.  Also font tag is obsolete and shouldn't be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reference your Interval with a variable.

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
....
....
....
},1000);


// Button Click ->
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have multiple intervals running at the same time so you need to clean them up using clearInterval(interval);

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
        {
            var minute = 60 * 2,
            display = document.querySelector('#time');
            begin(minute, display);

        });
var interval;

function myFunction()
{
var minute = 60 * 2,
display = document.querySelector('#time');
clearInterval(interval);
begin(minute, display);
}

function begin(duration, display) {
            var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
            interval = setInterval(function () {
                minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
                seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

                if (--timer < 0) 
                {
                    timer = duration;
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
```

something like this.

Answer (score 0):

In your my function reset the timer value using innerHTML or innerTEXT

```
function myFunction()
{
  var minute = 60 * 2,
  display = document.querySelector('#time');
  display.innerHTML = '02:00';
  begin(minute, display);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the setInterval. So make a global variable `var refreshIntervalId =  null`. Inside `begin()` function, insert this line at the top

```
if (refreshIntervalId) {
    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
}
```

and call setInterval like this

```
refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function () { ..
```

That is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript `setInterval()` method returns an interval Id which can be used to terminate/stop the interval. Using `clearInterval()` function the the loop of method execution can be stopped.

In you case just store the interval Id and on click event function add the `clearInterval(intervalId)` function and pass the interval Id.

```
var intervalId = null;
    myFunction(){
         if(intervalId != null){
          clearInterval(intervalId);
         }
    var minute = 60 * 2;
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
        begin(minute, display);
    }
```

Store the interval Id

```
intervaluId = setInterval(function(){ ....
                          },1000)
```